# Detect whether user has clicked on a specific link inside a Browser Control?

Tags: c#, .net, webkit

I'm not using the in-built browser control (ie wrapper) but i'm using Webkit.Net instead

When i click on `button1`, the WebkitBrowser will navigate to the link typed on `textBox1`

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/cocacola");
}
```

Can i detect when user click on the Like button ? For example when the user likes the page, a MessageBox appears and says that the page has been successfully liked !

Anyhelp would be highly appreciated

Comment: yes you can detect. The detection is your event handler itself. Why don't you just include the code for rendering your message in the click-handler?

Comment: I want a solution that let me detect the clicks by the Element ID or innerText because i want to use this with other websites too not with only this page.

Comment: Then you need a counter variable where you add +1 for every click. If you need it for several elements, then you need a counter variable for every element, or a counter array for all elements together.